# How to define a component as an array of another component in Open API?

Tags: yaml, openapi

I would like to define two components: one for a single student and one for an array of students. But I want to follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. So I tried this:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    student:
      type: object
      properties:
        StudentID:
          type: integer
          example: 3
        StudentName:
          type: string
          example: David
        StudentRemarks:
          type: string
          example: High Grade Student
    students:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/student/properties'
```

But it does not seem to work. Swaggers editor renders it this way:

[image: Swagger editor showing referenced properties.]

If I repeat myself:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    student:
      type: object
      properties:
        StudentID:
          type: integer
          example: 3
        StudentName:
          type: string
          example: David
        StudentRemarks:
          type: string
          example: High Grade Student
    students:
      type: array
      items:
        properties:
          StudentID:
            type: integer
            example: 3
          StudentName:
            type: string
            example: David
          StudentRemarks:
            type: string
            example: High Grade Student
```

It looks this way:

[image: Swagger editor showing repeated properties.]

When I try to define a [named anchor](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#named-anchors), I get the following error:

> ```
> Structural error at components.schemas.student
> should NOT have additional properties
> additionalProperty: $id
> ```

How to reference another component correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$ref` goes one level too deep. You need to point to a schema (or subschema) not the `properties` object within a schema.

```yaml
    students:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/student'
```